# Create a invite

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a command to invite myself to all servers of my bot is what can I do? I did his.

```py
@client.command()
async def inviteall(ctx):
  guild=client.guilds
  for i in list(client.guilds):
    invite = await ctx.guild.create_invite(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(invite)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here; You are trying to create an invite for the **whole guild** (which isn't possible). You can only create invites for **specific channels** (where your bot has create invite permissions).

Also you are trying to do this with `ctx` which would try to create an invite in **the guild the message was sent from**.

Another thing I noticed is that you are trying to send the **variable invite** and not the **url**.

Example:

```
@client.command()
async def inviteall(ctx):
  # guild=client.guilds    You can delete this if you don't need it somewhere else
  for i in list(client.guilds):
    channel = discord.utils.get(i, name="CHANNEL_NAME")
    # You can either you this /\ or this \/ (Both will not work)
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

    invite = await channel.create_invite(reason=reason) # If you haven't defined 'reason' before
    # this will get a problem
    
    await ctx.send(invite.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only create an invite to specific channels. A good way to do this is to get an invite to the guild's `system_channel`. If it is None, you can try for each channel of the guild.

```
async def inviteToGuild(guild, reason):
    systemChannel = guild.system_channel
    if systemChannel is not None: 
        invite = await systemChannel.create_invite(reason=reason)
    else:
        # For each channel of the guild, try to create an invite
    return invite
```

Then just execute this function for all guilds in your `client.guilds`!